# HTML Unit - login to secure website using form - can't connect to page after form

Tags: htmlunit

I'm a newbie to java htmlunit so any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to login to a webpage that is protected with username and password authentication by submitting a username and password to the form on the webpage using htmlunit to mirror the actions of a web browser. The website itself has form based authorisation.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

//Import htmlunit classes    

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie;


//This Class attempts to submit user and password credentials
//and mirrors how a login button would be clicked on a webpage:

public class submitForm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        // Get the first page
        HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://cmdbjr/frameset.php?ci_name=&ci_id=&ci_type=");

        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form,
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("loginform");

        // Enter login and passwd
        form.getInputByName("user_id").setValueAttribute("#####");
        form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("#####");

        // Click "Sign In" button/link
        page1 = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Log In").click();

        // I added the cookie section but this returns a null pointer exception    
        Set<Cookie> cookie = webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies();

        if(cookie != null){

            Iterator<Cookie> i = cookie.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {

                webClient.getCookieManager().addCookie(i.next());

            }

        }


        //  Get page as Html
        String htmlBody = page1.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        //  Save the response in a file
        String filePath = "c:/temp/test_out.html";

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));
        bw.write(htmlBody);
        bw.close();

        // Change the value of the text field
        // userField.setValueAttribute("alwalsh");
        // passwordField.setValueAttribute("1REland6");

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        // final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();


        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

If I run the code without the cookie section of code the page I am trying to reach which 
is after the login page doesn't appear an error page appears saying I'm not connected to the internet.

If the code is run with the cookie section the error:

> Exception in thread "main" >java.lang.NullPointerException at contentWeb.main(contentWeb.java:26)

is returned.

I'm new to java htmlunit so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your example with my yahoo mail login credentials and it worked. However, I added  : `webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);` to ignore exceptions on script errors.