# Download facebook page source code

Tags: java, facebook

I need to download source code of a certain facebook page.
So I thought I would log in to the facebook, and then download source.
But that information about me logged in is simply lost, and when I try to download source code rom another url it appears I am still logged out for my application.

So here is my code:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");
        final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("login_form");

        final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0);
        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
        textField.setValueAttribute("email");
        final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
        textField2.setValueAttribute("password");
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();


        HtmlPage weread = webClient.getPage("http://apps.facebook.com/ireadit/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0");

                  System.out.println(weread.asXml());



    }
```

I hope you understand my idea..any suggestions how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which you didn't specify in your question.

Authentication works with cookies. You have not incorporated that into your code. When you first login, the server sends you cookies, which you need to capture and resend with subsequent requests. I am not very familiar with HtmlUnit, but it looks like it has a CookieManager class which you can use to get the cookies like this:

```
webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies();
```

You may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609474/html-unit-login-to-secure-website-using-form-cant-connect-to-page-after-for).